# How to connect to monogodb using monk?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a nodejs app using expressjs framework. I would like to ask how do we connect to mongodb using monk? i found this code online however it seems that we do not need to specify username and password. why is that so?

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');
```

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two methods of passing username/password:

```
// first:
var db = monk('USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/nodetest1');

// second:
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1', {
  username : 'USERNAME',
  password : 'PASSWORD'
});
```

It's not very well documented, but since `monk` uses `mongoskin`, you can look [here](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin#dbserverurls-dboptions-replicasetoptions) for more information.

Comment: can we use monk to connect to remote mongodb servers? 
say mongodb in mongolab?

Comment: @vignesh I don't see why not.

Comment: I will add a new SO question so that you can check the details

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668288/not-able-to-connect-to-mongodb-hosted-on-remote-server-using-monk

Answer (score 3):

I want to add an alternative to the answers above as neither worked for me.

So the way I was able to connect to a `mongod --auth` instance was:

1.Make sure you create a user while logged into mongodb as a user with appropriate permissions to create users on databases (like a user with the role `userAdminAnyDatabase`). If you don't have a user with this role restart mongo with just `mongod` without `--auth` and login as your superuser (if you have one) or with a simple `mongo` command and make this user with the appropriate privileges.

I highly recommend reading up on mongodb roles here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

2.Once you are logged into your database instance with the appropriate user who is supposed to be creating other users, type `use db_name` where db_name is the name of your database that you want to make the user for.

3.Once *inside* this database use the db.createUser command like so: `db.createUser({user:"your_username", pwd:"your_password", roles:["your_role"]})` 
It's documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/

4.Then just use `db = monk('USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/DATABASE_NAME')` in your code.

After you've done this you should be able to log into a running mongod --auth instance with a user for the particular database you created that user for.

For anyone curious I'm developing a little web app in [Koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa). Using monk and [co-monk](https://github.com/tj/co-monk).

Answer (score 0):

In `apps.js`:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/ta');
module.exports = db;
```

In `/lib/mylib.js`:

```
var db = require('../apps.js')
```

Though i would recommend making a separate file called db.js and in that file export the connection ,that is more cleaner.