# not able to connect to mongodb hosted on remote server using monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am using node js, and for the backend i am using mongodb

For connecting to DB, if i use the below line, it is fetching data

```
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest2');
```

But if i change that to below line, its not fetching the data

```
var db = monk('mongodb://username:password@XXX.mongolab.com:27483/userdb');
```

I have created the collection with same name in both places

```
router.get('/userlist', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('userlist');
    collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: You should start by adding error handling. I can connect to that database just fine (but I can't perform queries because I don't have the correct username/password, so queries return an authentication error).

Comment: thanks @robertklep will do that
are there any config/settings level changes that i have to do to enable this?

Comment: You should first find out why the queries aren't working; using a standalone script for that is easiest; if you get any errors (the `e` variable in the query callback), log them so you get an idea what's going on (perhaps username/password mismatch).

Comment: This is likely permissions and nothing to do with monk. Try connections from the shell and where that does not work, go back to your mongolab account and change permissions until you have something working.

Comment: Thanks robertklep, blakes Seven
Its permission issue, i tried with different user id and password and it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your IP is whitelisted.
2. try to connect via shell

Add an error handling.

```
const db = require("monk")(uri);
db.then(() => {
  console.log('Connected correctly to server')
})
```